# In PowerShell, is there a way to dispose of Send-MailMessage resources?

Tags: powershell, email

I've written a PowerShell script that sends an email message. Originally I used the Send-MailMessage commandlet.

```
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $MailServer `
-To $MailTo `
-From $MailFrom `
-Subject $MailSubject `
-Body $MailBody
```

This is concise.  But if I execute the script rapidly in succession on my workstation, the following error appears in the PowerShell console.

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established
>   connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

What I suspect is that resources aren't being released or that a thread is getting blocked.  Below is my current workaround, which has the advantage of being disposable.  And I can run this in rapid succession with no transport connection errors.  But this is more verbose than Send-MailMessage.

```
[object]$SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
[object]$MailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$SMTPClient.Host = $MailServer
$MailMessage.To.Add($MailTo)
$MailMessage.From = $MailFrom
$MailMessage.Subject = $MailSubject
$MailMessage.Body = $MailBody
$SMTPClient.Send($MailMessage)
$MailMessage.Dispose()
$SMTPClient.Dispose()
```

Is there some way to force Send-MailMessage to release resources when I'm done with it, perhaps via Dispose or a C# style using statement?  Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like potential TCP port exhaustion or you're getting tar pitted by the remote server.  How many messages are you trying to send?

Comment: Once it's deployed on the server it will essentially be just one email per day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frankly, "it works but it's verbose" shouldn't be a huge concern, especially when "verbose" means 10 lines.  And I mean, you can simplify your syntax by using the class constructors:

```
$SMTPClient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient -ArgumentList $MailServer
$MailMessage = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Mail.MailMessage -ArgumentList $MailFrom, $MailTo, $MailSubject, $MailBody
$SMTPClient.Send($MailMessage)
$MailMessage.Dispose()
$SMTPClient.Dispose()
```

Comment: Not to mention, that this functionality could (should) then be wrapped in a function, which is used where needed.

Comment: Thanks for showing me the class constructors.  You're right, "verbose" at 10 lines isn't a big deal, but this will be part of a larger script, so any line savings for clarity is nice. Since PowerShell is new for me, one thought was that I overlooked some obvious deconstructor.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comment, you could be overflowing whatever buffer there is for the cmdlet.  This answer is more a point on style for the future (less chance of mistakes happening) by using splatting:

```
$MailMessage = @{
  SmtpServer = $MailServer;
  To         = $MailTo;
  From       = $MailFrom;
  Subject    = $MailSubject;
  Body       = $MailBody;
}

Send-MailMessage @MailMessage
```

Edit-
This can also be done with the selected answer:

```
$Client = @{
  TypeName = 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient';
  ArgumentList = $MailServer;
}
$Message = @{
  TypeName = 'System.Net.Mail.MailMessage';
  ArgumentList = @($MailFrom,$MailTo,$MailSubject,$MailBody);
}
$SMTPClient = New-Object @Client
$MailMessage = New-Object @Message
```